# Using IComparer to get index where DateTime is greater than

Tags: c#, datetime, icomparer

Given:

```
List<DateTime> descOrderedDates;
```

And a datetime:

```
DateTime fromDate;
```

I can easily count the number of items where the date is greater than `fromDate` as follows:

```
var count = descOrderedDates.Count(c=> c > fromDate);
```

However I'm struggling to implement this as a `BinarySearch`:

```
var ix = descOrderedDates.BinarySearch(fromDate, new CompareDates());

private class CompareDates : IComparer<DateTime>
{
    public int Compare(DateTime compareDate, DateTime fromDate)
    {
        if (fromDate > compareDate) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This keeps returning `1` in a test case where `fromDate` is less than the smallest date in the list.  I'm struggling to wrap my head around `IComparer`, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You could implement that `Compare()` as `return compareDate.CompareTo(fromDate);` - but at that point, why would you need it? It just repeats what `DateTime.CompareTo()` already does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to return either a negative value, a positive value, or 0 in `Compare`, depending on whether the parameters are greater than, less than, or equal to each other, as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1.compare?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_IComparer_1_Compare__0__0_) says. (So your implementation of not returning negative values at all is incorrect.)

You can do that by explicitly writing out the three cases and comparing the dates with `<` and `>`, but `DateTime` has the [`CompareTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.compareto?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_CompareTo_System_Object_) method (as it implements `IComparable`), so you can just use that instead:

```
public int Compare(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
    => date2.CompareTo(date1);
```

Note that the order of the two dates are reversed when we call `CompareTo`, to achieve the descending order for the `Comparer` that we are implementing.

If you want to find the first index of the list with a date that is less than `fromDate`, you also need to do some checking on `ix`:

```
int firstIndexLessThanFromDate;
if (ix < 0) {
    // applying bitwise not gives you where the element should be inserted
    // i.e. the index of the next smallest element
    firstIndexLessThanFromDate = ~ix;
} else {
    firstIndexLessThanFromDate = ix + 1;
}
```

Comment: This returns the first index where the dates are equal, but he wants the fist where it's greater

Comment: @TimSchmelter Is that what OP wanted? I understood the question wrong then :( But somehow they still accepted 

Comment: Just check what `BinarySearch` actually returns. It does not just return "first index where dates are equal".

Comment: @Sweeper: well, look at it's title :D

Comment: @TimSchmelter I reread the question again. In the first comment, you mean he wants the first where **fromDate** is greater _than the element at that index, not the other way round, right? (because otherwise it's a simple check of the first element)

Answer (score 1):

Your comparer returns 1 in case of `fromDate > compareDate`, but it should also return -1 in the opposite case, and 0 only if they're equal. And do you need a custom comparer at all? I believe for dates the default comparison will work fine.